# How to replace just a file name in a file path with pattern

Tags: python

```
def listFiles(dir):
    rootdir = dir
        for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
            for file in files:
                yield os.path.join(root,file)
        return

    for f in listFiles(target):
        if pattern in f:
             os.rename(f,f.replace(pattern,'REPLACED'))
```

I have a file such as:

```
 "C:\Dir3.30\file_3.30.xml"
```

If I do

```
os.rename(f,f.replace(pattern,'REPLACED'))
```

both the occurances would be replaced. 
How can I make sure that just the file name is being replaced

I want:

```
"C:\Dir3.30\file_REPLACED.xml"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the filename off with [`os.path.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split), call `str.replace()` on just the name, and re-join:

```
path, name = os.path.split(f)
os.rename(f, os.path.join(path, name.replace(pattern, 'REPLACED')))
```